# offsetof(type, array[run_time_value]) failing in g++ - Regression?

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer

We have code that uses `offsetof` with a runtime value. Example:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

struct type {
    int array[4];
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    return offsetof(type, array[argc]);
}
```

It doesn't matter which C++ version I compile with. [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) 11.1 and later says:

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:8:33: error: 'argc' is not a constant expression
    8 |     return offsetof(type, array[argc]);
      |                                 ^~~~
```

This compiles in our older (pre 11.1) g++ compilers and the most up to date versions of clang++, MSVC and icx all accept it and "do the right thing". I'm confused about the wording in the standard.

From [C++20 first post-publication draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf):

> 17.2.4 Sizes, alignments, and offsets [support.types.layout]
>
> 1. The macro `offsetof(type, member-designator )` has the same semantics as the corresponding macro in the C standard library header `<stddef.h>`, but accepts a restricted set of *type* arguments in this document. Use of the `offsetof` macro with a *type* other than a standard-layout class (11.2) is conditionally-supported.
>
>    The expression `offsetof(type, member-designator )` is **never *type*-dependent** (13.8.3.3) and it is **valued-dependent** (13.8.3.4) if and **only if *type* is dependent**. The result of applying the `offsetof` macro to a static data member or a function member is undefined. No operation invoked by the `offsetof` macro shall throw an exception and `noexcept(offsetof(type, member-designator ))` shall be `true`.

From this I get that the `offsetof` expression ...

- is never type-dependent.
- is only value-dependent if *type* is dependent.

I interpret this as g++ comes to the conclusion that the expression is not valuedependent while all the others agree that it is.

##### Main question:

- Is [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) right or wrong? There is a closed [bugreport](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95942) regarding this, which claims g++ does the right thing, but it doesn't mention the value-dependent part.

###### Bonus:

- An explanation or example of what it means for the *type* to be dependent while the expression is not type-dependent would be great.

---

The section on value-dependent expressions didn't help me to understand if g++ is right or wrong but perhaps there is something in there that I missed so I include that too:

> 13.8.3.4 Value-dependent expressions [temp.dep.constexpr]
>
> 1. Except as described below, an expression used in a context where a constant expression is required is
>    value-dependent if any subexpression is value-dependent.
> 2. An id-expression is value-dependent if:
>    (2.1) — it is a concept-id and any of its arguments are dependent,
>    (2.2) — it is type-dependent,
>    (2.3) — it is the name of a non-type template parameter,
>    (2.4) — it names a static data member that is a dependent member of the current instantiation and is not initialized in a member-declarator,
>    (2.5) — it names a static member function that is a dependent member of the current instantiation, or
>    (2.6) — it names a potentially-constant variable (7.7) that is initialized with an expression that is valuedependent.
>    Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if the unary-expression or expression is type-dependent or the type-id is dependent:
>    `sizeof unary-expression`
>    `sizeof ( type-id )`
>    `typeid ( expression )`
>    `typeid ( type-id )`
>    `alignof ( type-id )`
>    `noexcept ( expression )`
>    [Note 1 : For the standard library macro `offsetof`, see 17.2. — end note]
> 3. Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if either the type-id or simple-type-specifier is dependent or the expression or cast-expression is value-dependent:
>    `simple-type-specifier ( expression-listopt )`
>    `static_cast < type-id > ( expression )`
>    `const_cast < type-id > ( expression )`
>    `reinterpret_cast < type-id > ( expression )`
>    `( type-id ) cast-expression`
> 4. Expressions of the following form are value-dependent:
>    `sizeof ... ( identifier )`
>    *fold-expression*
> 5. An expression of the form *&qualified-id* where the qualified-id names a dependent member of the current instantiation is value-dependent. An expression of the form *&cast-expression* is also value-dependent if evaluating cast-expression as a core constant expression (7.7) succeeds and the result of the evaluation refers to a templated entity that is an object with static or thread storage duration or a member function.

Comment: Offsetof has a lively discussion over on C side: [As a result of the lack of clarity, implementations diverge in what offsetof expressions they accept](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2396.htm#dr_496). My naïve reading of it is that it is supposed to [expand to a constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) which your case doesn't.

Comment: Not what you're looking for but, out of curiosity: Is `return offsetof(type, array) + sizeof (decltype(*type::array)) * argc;` a work around?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95942

Comment: teapot418: Thanks, I'll read up on this there. Scheff'sCat: Yeah, making a replacement isn't a big deal. We made it `offsetof(type, array) + argc * sizeof type::array[0]`. @AlanBirtles Nice! That bug-report is a perfect match. I'm still not sure they came to the right conclusion though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms *value-dependent* and *type-dependent* have nothing to do with your issue. These terms are used to specify how lookup in templates is handled, nothing more. (The implicit meaning of "*dependent*" is always more or less something like "*dependent on a template parameter*".)

To see whether your usage is correct or not, you need to look at the C specification referred to by the C++ specification instead.

C requires for example in [draft N3096](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) §7.21:

> The type and member designator shall be such that given
>
> ```
> static type t;
> ```
>
> then the expression `&(t.member-designator)` evaluates to an address constant.

An *address constant* can't access the value of any object according to C and even if you would extend the restriction to constant expressions more like common in C++, then the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `argc` still disqualifies the expression as a core constant expression.

There are other problems with the specification of `offsetof`'s *member-designator*, e.g. what happens if you used an integer literal instead of `argc` in the array subscript, but I think in your case it is relatively clear.

`offsetof` is also required to be an integer constant expression (see also §7.21), so its result can't possibly rely on a runtime value.

Comment: I've now read [C DR 496](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2396.htm#dr_496) and more and have come to lean towards your interpretation too. I'll leave the question open for ~24 hours though to see if anything else comes in.